# set each same class div background image from jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

the code look like that

html :

```
<div class="imgbg"></div>

<div class="imgbg"></div>
```

jquery :

```
var imgSet = [
    "bg1.jpg", // i wanna set this image to first div (class="img bg")
    "bg2.jpg", // this for 2
    "bg3.jpg" // and 3
];
```

i wanna place the image **background** to each div that class name is imgbg
what should i do to next?
any idea to made this function work? thank so much

Comment: I have been voted negative several times for not adding enough information or a jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a `.each()` over the class `.immgbg`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // DOM is ready here
    $("div.imgbg").each(function(i){

        $(this).css({"background-image", "url("+imgSet[i]+")"});

    });
});
```